# File download from server using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, download

I have created a PHP page that allows users to download a file when they click the this link:

```
<a href="download_pdf.php?pubid=<?php echo $row_rsPublications['pubID']; ?>&amp;file=<?php echo $row_rsPublications['file']; ?>">Download File</a>
```

I have also created the download page that the link directs to:

```
<?php 

 if(isset($_GET['file'])) {

    $fileID = $_GET['pubid'];
    $filename= ($_GET['file']);
    $path = "admin/pubfiles/";
    $fullPath = $path . $filename;
    mysql_select_db($database_connDioceseofife, $connDioceseofife);
    $sql  = "SELECT file FROM publications WHERE pubID = $fileID";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($filename == NULL) {
        die('No file exists or the name is invalid!');
        }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($fullPath);

}
?>
```

Now my problem is, when the download popup window come up, it reads that the file is of 0 bytes. And when downloaded, it can't open. i get the message that it is not a supported file type or its been damaged or corrupted.

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you do a `var_dump(file_exists($filename))` before your head declarations?

Comment: **[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? Learn about _[prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)_ instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @Jamie: I am not too ok at php. But i believe what you are asking is to verify if the file exists. I know the file is on my sever. I can see it in the folder. But to be sure, i have added: if($filename == NULL) { die('The name is invalid!');} but i still get an empty file

Comment: @nlsbshtr: Don't understand what you mean by flushing the content.

Comment: @nlsbshtr: I have added the path to the file and the readfile() and also the flush() but still the same problem

Comment: @Wezy: please explain further on the use of $row['file'] in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the query result in $row.

Use $row['file'] to get the actual file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for assisting me. I have been able to solve the problem after further reading. I have updated the initial script i wrote. what is above is now the working script.
What i did was to include `$fullpath = $path . $filename` then changed the `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");` and then the readfile function from `readfile($path)` to `readfile($fullpath)`.
Thanks again @nlsbshtr and everybody else for your help.

Comment: Michael, you should remove the piece of code that queries your database. You don't need it for this purpose, apparently.